# Hide event indicator in Month view on iPhone

Tags: iphone, calendar

IOS 16.0.3 on iPhone 11

I have events in my calendar for my father's caregivers, so I can see who is there on any particular day. They are all day events so they take up little space in my view.  In the Month view, each day has a gray dot if there is an event on that day. So in my calendar, every day has a gray dot since there is a caregiver every day. This makes the dot useless for seeing if there is something important on that day.

Is there a way to configure an entry that doesn't trigger the gray dot in the Month view? Or maybe set up a different type of event that shows me the name without getting in the way of other events?

I would rather not create a separate calendar because then I would have to constantly turn it on and off.

Comment: Try making a separate calendar for your father’s care givers. This way, you only see those events when you select that calendar.

Comment: See my last line. I am going to use Google's calendar since Apple's one won't work easily.

Comment: That’s the workaround for what you’re looking to do.  You don’t need a whole new account, just an alternate calendar.

Comment: See my last line. I know what the workaround is. I was looking for a real solution. The calendar already has entries that don't cause that gray dot (holidays, birthdays). I just want to be able to create them.